# VisualStudio - How to specify the path to dlls that are uses as references

Tags: .net, visual-studio, dll

I have a web project that I'm deploying to Azure.  It also has a webjob associated with it.  They both use a DLL called foo.dll, but the webjob project uses a slightly older version of foo.dll.  The webjob project is in a completely different VS solution.

In a bid to streamline my deployment process, I've added the webjob bin files to the App_Data folder of my web project, so that when its deployed the webjob is too.

So I have foo.dll in the following locations:

- MySolution/MyWebProject/Dependencies/foo.dll
- MySolution/MyWebProject/App_Data/jobs/triggered/MyWebJob/foo.dll

I then add the reference to the foo.dll in the Dependencies folder to the web project.  It builds fine, but when I run/debug it, I get a MissingMethodException on a method that exists in the Dependencies/foo.dll version, but doesn't exist in the MyWebJob/foo.dll version.

How can I ensure the correct dll is used in my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I solved it using DLL version numbers and manually editing the csproj file.  Originally, the references in the csproj looked like this:

```
<Reference Include="Foo">
  <HintPath>Dependencies\Foo.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

I started incrementing the assembly version number in Foo.dll and then edited my csproj file to contain the required version number and a line telling it that a specific version was to be used:

```
<Reference Include="Foo, Version=1.0.0.1">
  <SpecificVersion>True</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>Dependencies\Foo.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Now, it copies the correct DLL to the bin folder.  Hope this helps someone else at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide details on the .net framework version you are running?
I would try the following things
1) Check if the azure instance is running the same .net version as you are locally
2) Try a clean, rebuild of dependent dlls to clear out any stale dlls.

Comment: .NET 4.6.  I've tried a complete clean and rebuild.  I've tried removing all references, deleting the dlls from the Dependencies folder, performing a clean, then adding the dlls back, referencing them and then building.  It builds fine, but throws the MissingMethodException when running.  If I remove the webjob folder it works perfectly.  It happens both locally AND on Azure.  Upon further investigation, VS or msbuild is copying the wrong dll to the bin folder - yet when I delete the webjob folder it copies the correct one.